# Choose random number distribution at compile time

Tags: c++, googletest

I am writing tests using the `TYPED_TEST` feature of google tests, which allows me to generalize a test to multiple types. I am testing a class template for the types `int` and `double`. In a test, I would need to generate random numbers. To do so, I have tried using the `std::uniform_int_distribution<T>` and the `std::uniform_real_distribution<T>` but have ran into static asserts.

As the names indicate, [`std::uniform_int_distribution<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/) checks if `T` is an integral type and [`std::uniform_real_distribution<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/) checks that `T` is a floating point type.

Since my test automatically tests for `int` and then for `double`, I have been trying to write some kind of function that would allow me to chose the right kind of distribution for the type at compile time. More precisely, something like:

```
template<class T>
Distribution get_right_distribution(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    if(T is integral) // Compile time is needed, runtime 
                      // fails since both if and else have to compile
    {
        return std::uniform_real_distribution(a, b);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::uniform_real_distribution(a, b);
    }
}
```

Note that this is only a pseudocode of what I have been trying to do. This kind of logical branch fails because the `if` AND the `else` have to compile.

I have done some research on how to do this and I feel like `std::is_integral<T>` and `std::is_floating_point<T>` are part of the solution, but I have not been able to compile anything so far. I mainly tried two things:

1. Make a kind of compilation time by using template specialization.
2. Use `enable_if`.

Using the first approach I ended up with an error message telling me my overloads were ambiguous. Using the second approach, I tried some stuff but got lost in the abominable syntax (at least for someone not used to it) which it lead to.

Do you have a suggestion on how this could be accomplished?

P.S. I would like to see how this could be done, so splitting my test in two would not be an acceptable answer for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### C++17

I you may use C++17, you can make use of `if constexpr(...)`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
auto get_right_distribution(const T a, const T b) {
    if constexpr(std::is_integral<T>::value) {
        return std::uniform_int_distribution(a, b);
    }
    else {
        return std::uniform_real_distribution(a, b);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    auto int_dis = get_right_distribution(1, 6);
    std::cout << int_dis(gen) << "\n";

    auto float_dis = get_right_distribution(1.F, 6.F);
    std::cout << float_dis(gen) << "\n";
}
```

#### C++11 & C++14

For C++11 and C++14, you could use a conditional extra template type parameter in your template parameter list to select the return type as well as the distribution.

C++11:

```
template <typename T,
          typename Distribution = typename std::conditional<
              std::is_integral<T>::value, 
              std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
              std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>::type>
Distribution get_right_distribution(const T a, const T b) {
    return Distribution(a, b);
}
```

C++ 14 (return type deduced by `auto` and using the `std::conditional_t` helper type short form for `std::conditional<...>::type`):

```
template <typename T,
          typename Distribution = typename std::conditional_t<
              std::is_integral<T>::value, 
              std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
              std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>>
auto get_right_distribution(const T a, const T b) {
    return Distribution(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Just tested the C++11 answer (it was the one I needed) and it worked exactly as advertised. C++17 better describes what I had in mind, good to know.

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes use [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) like this:

```
template<typename Number>
Number random_number(Number from, Number to)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<Number>::value
               || std::is_floating_point<Number>::value,
                   "parameters must be integer or floating point types");

    using Distribution = typename std::conditional
    <
        std::is_integral<Number>::value,
        std::uniform_int_distribution<Number>,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<Number>
    >::type;

    // in reality I usually get the generator from another
    // function, but for many purposes this is fine.
    thread_local static std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    thread_local static Distribution dist;

    return dist(mt, typename Distribution::param_type{from, to});
}
```

If you pass the function integer parameters it selects the `int` distribution otherwise it selects the `real` distribution.

Comment: I believe that typename in the return is not necessary. Furthermore, if you use c++14, then you can get rid off the other one as well, by using std::conditional_t (::type is unnecessary then as well). And if you are not using c++14 then condional_t is really easy to write on your own, so might be worth considering.

Comment: @paler123 Unfortunately `typename` is necessary in the return because `param_type` is a template parameter dependant type.

Comment: Agreed, sry could've checked.