# Template function for random number generation (static assertion failed)

Tags: c++, templates, random, static

I created a simple template function to generate a random number of type T (I need int or float) in range [low, high) as follows:

```
template <typename T>
T randm(T low, T high)
{
    static std::random_device seeder;
    static std::mt19937 gen(seeder());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(low, high);
    return dis(gen);
}
```

However when I try to call it as:

```
int r = randm<int>(0, 10);
```

I get the error: "static assertion failed: result_type must be a floating point type".

I found out that if I use `uniform_real_distribution<>` instead of `uniform_real_distribution<T>`, it works, but I am not sure why (and if I am not mistaken `uniform_real_distribution<>` defaults to double which I don't need).

Comment: For integral types, there is [uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). You have to apply something with `if constexpr` or to use SFNIAE (with type traits) to handle floating points and integrals separately. Btw. there is a note in [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution): _The effect is undefined if this is not one of float, double, or long double._ ("this" concerns the template type.)

Comment: So I guess it's easier to write two separate functions one for floats and one for integers.

Comment: _two separate functions one for floats and one for integers_ This is one option. Even in this case, you may use the SFINAE approach as there are more than one floating point type as well as more than one integral type.

Comment: Related to [choose-random-number-distribution-at-compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021277/choose-random-number-distribution-at-compile-time) and [templating-a-random-number-generator-in-c/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645963/templating-a-random-number-generator-in-c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integral types, there is [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). You have to apply something with `if constexpr` or to use SFNIAE (with type traits) to handle floating points and integrals separately. Btw. there is a note in [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution): *The effect is undefined if this is not one of float, double, or long double.* ("this" concerns the template type.)

Two separate functions distinguished by SFINAE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template <typename T,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0
>
T randm(T low, T high)
{
    static std::random_device seeder;
    static std::mt19937 gen(seeder());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dis(low, high);
    return dis(gen);
}

template <typename T,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, int> = 0
>
T randm(T low, T high)
{
    static std::random_device seeder;
    static std::mt19937 gen(seeder());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(low, high);
    return dis(gen);
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(std::cout << randm(0, 10) << std::endl);
  DEBUG(std::cout << randm(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl);
}
```

Output:

```
std::cout << randm(0, 10) << std::endl;
4
std::cout << randm(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl;
9.05245
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e8a9e03e33c8d5f)

---

Using `if constexpr` (requires at least C++17):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

template <typename T>
T randm(T low, T high)
{
  static std::random_device seeder;
  static std::mt19937 gen(seeder());
  if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dis(low, high);
    return dis(gen);
  }
  if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dis(low, high);
    return dis(gen);
  }
  return T(); // ERROR?
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(std::cout << randm(0, 10) << std::endl);
  DEBUG(std::cout << randm(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl);
}
```

Output:

```
std::cout << randm(0, 10) << std::endl;
7
std::cout << randm(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl;
3.51174
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf7c98fd814789f9)

---

Inspired by [Jarod42s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018040/template-function-for-random-number-generation-static-assertion-failed/70018361?noredirect=1#comment123777298_70018361) another C++11 solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T randm(T low, T high)
{
  static std::random_device seeder;
  static std::mt19937 gen(seeder());
  typename std::conditional<std::is_integral<T>::value,
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T>,
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T>
  >::type dis(low, high);
  return dis(gen);
}

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  DEBUG(std::cout << randm(0, 10) << std::endl);
  DEBUG(std::cout << randm(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl);
}
```

Output:

```
std::cout << randm(0, 10) << std::endl;
2
std::cout << randm(0.0f, 10.0f) << std::endl;
4.36778
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7c3ed0b0e278238)

---

[Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018040/template-function-for-random-number-generation-static-assertion-failed/70018361?noredirect=1#comment123777780_70018361) also pointed out another weakness of this approach: [std::is_integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) covers any integral type (including variations of `char` and even `bool`) but [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is actually undefined if the template type *is not one of short, int, long, long long, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, or unsigned long long*.

A better alternative is provided in this [answer to **templating a random number generator in c++**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69646192/7478597).

Comment: Something like `std::conditional_t<std::is_integral<T>, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>` is another alternative.

Comment: @Jarod42 Cool. I was not yet aware of [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) (and what it's good for)...

Comment: And note, as we can see in linked answer, that the actual condition is naive, `std::uniform_int_distribution<char>` is wrong, even if `char` is integral.

Comment: @Jarod42 With a bit of luck, the attempt to use the approach for `bool` or `char` might end up in a `static_assert()` as reported by OP initially for `std::uniform_real_distribution`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), `uniform_real_distribution` has such declaration:

```cpp
template< class RealType = double >
class uniform_real_distribution;

// ctor
explicit uniform_real_distribution( RealType a, RealType b = 1.0 );
```

So when you used the form `uniform_real_distribution<>`, it actually substitute the `RealType` as `double`(obtained from default template arguments). However, when you use `uniform_real_distribution<T>`, you actually specific the `RealType` as `T`(in your sample case, which is `int`), thus cause the some `static_assert` check failure in the implementation of `uniform_real_distribution`.